# Am I using the saxon genitive where I shouldn't?

Tags: saxon-genitive

I have been edited in [some SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159091/make-section-links-in-the-table-of-contents-point-to-the-top-of-sections-page) while using the saxon genitive in the next sentence, where I'm referring to the ToC of the corresponding MWE.

*In this' MWE ToC A and B should link to the same point.*

The edition was to change *this'* with *this*. What is the problem there?

["when talking about things that belong to other things"](http://innovatenglish.blogspot.com.es/2011/10/saxon-genetive.html)

Comment: The only time it is correct to use an apostrophe after _this_ is when it is being used as a "word as a word". There are too many _this_'s in this sentence. [plural form] / I think that _this_ 's short form will make it possible to fit it on the sign. [possessive form] Arguably, even they are better avoided.

Comment: So the problem in the sentence is just the word *this*, isn't it? Are there more words to be aware of when using *'s*?

Comment: At [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1017) useful thread is: "The exception to the possessive rule is that pronouns show possession without the use of 's". ... my, mine, your, yours, his, her, hers, our, ours, their, theirs, its, whose, etc. >> "One's" (as in One must mind one's p's and q's) is an exception to the exception! There is also the infuriating but famous 'double possessive': a friend of John's (but an ally of France).

Comment: Certain words take the preposition *of* rather than the apostrophe, depending on their meaning. *This* is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possessive of "this dog" is "this dog's". Not "this' dog", which is nonsensical and ungrammatical.

Likewise, the possessive of "this MWE" is "this MWE's". Not "this' MWE", which is nonsensical and ungrammatical.

Comment: this' dog = the dog belonging to "this". Nonsensical, sure, however not wholly ungrammatical

Comment: @msam: I would say "this's dog". I would not say "this' dog". Your dialect may vary.